# Asp.Net Api not returning error to angularjs error method

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, angularjs-factory

I have a Ionic app that works with asp.net web api, 
There I have a HttpResponseMessage,

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/products/search/{term}/{page}")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage SearchProducts(string term, int page)
{
    List<Product> list = AppDataAccess.SearchProducts(term, page);
    if (list == null)
    { return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Error"); }
    else
    { return Request.CreateResponse<IEnumerable<Product>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, list);}
}
```

Angular js 1.3 Factory:

```
factory.searching = function(term, page) {
      return $http.get(urlBase + 'products' + '/search/' + term + '/' + page );
    };
```

And a controller function

```
$scope.searching = function() {
      productFactory.searching($scope.term, 1 )
      .success(function(products) {
        $scope.products = products;
      }).error(function(error) {
        alertsFactory.showError();
      });
    };
```

The code works perfectly, it returns the items that I am searching for. 
But I have some doubts about handling errors, what would happen if I drop the store procedure?  It should return me an error, in this case the error is catched and saved in a database with Elmah, it returns a Request.CreateErrorResponse, but in the controller function the response is received in the success method, is this right? shouldn't be receiving this response in the error method?

Any advice??

thanks 
Alberto

Answer (score 0):

If an exception is thrown and unhandled by yourself then WebAPI will send a status back of 500 (Internal Server Error) - your Angular request will interpret this as an error.